# How to use a function that takes arguments with jQuery's change() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I'm using jQuery version 1.5. 
I am looking at jQuery's [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function
 and specifically at this bit:

```
.change( [ eventData ], handler(eventObject) )
eventData: A map of data that will be passed to the event handler.
handler(eventObject): A function to execute each time the event is triggered.
```

What exactly is a "map of data" in JavaScript? How can I use the following test function as an event handler?

```
var myHandler = function(msg){alert(msg);};
```

I've tried this:

```
$("select#test").change(["ok"], myHandler);
```

and the alert reports [object Object]

Answer (score 69, accepted):

See [`event.data`](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/). The data is not passed as argument to handler, but as property of the event object:

```
$("select#test").change({msg: "ok"},  function(event) {
    alert(event.data.msg);
});
```

The handler always only accepts one argument, which is the `event` object. This is the reason why your alert shows `"[object Object]"`, your function is printing the event object.
If you want to use functions with custom arguments, you have to wrap them into another function:

```
$("select#test").change({msg: "ok"},  function(event) {
    myHandler(event.data.msg);
});
```

or just

```
$("select#test").change(function(event) {
    myHandler("ok");
});
```

---

Btw. the selector is better written as `$('#test')`. IDs are (should be) unique. There is no need to prepend the tag name.

Comment: One thing to note about this is that the $(this) that myHandler receives is different when called this way.  If you need your original $(this) you could pass it as a parameter after "ok".

Answer (score 13):

> What exactly is a "map of data" in Javascript?

Basically just an object, e.g.:

```
var data = {
    foo: "I'm foo",
    bar: "I'm bar"
};
```

All JavaScript objects are essentially maps (aka "dictionaries" aka "associative arrays").

> How can I use the following test function as an event handler?

By wrapping it in another function:

```
$("select#test").change(function() {
    myHandler($(this).val());
});
```

That calls `myHandler` with the value of the select box whenever it changes.

If you want to use the `eventData` part, add an object prior to the handler:

```
$("select#test").change({
    foo: "I'm foo"
}, function(event) {
    myHandler(event.data.foo, $(this).val());
});
```

That calls `myHandler` with the "I'm foo" as the first argument, then the value of the select box, whenever it changes.