# How to pass parameter when doing Jquery change with function name only syntax?

Tags: jquery

If I have a function:

```
function doSomething() {
   ///
}
```

I can use this with .change as follows:

```
$("input[name='bla']").change(doSomething);
```

However, what if the function was:

```
function doSomething(bla) {
   ///
}
```

And I wanted to pass "this" as a parameter to the function? This doesn't seem to work:

```
$("input[name='bla']").change(doSomething(this));
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I do not want this:

```
$('a.link').change(function (e) { doSomething($(this)); } );
```

I want this: (but the correct syntax that will work)

```
$('a.link').change( doSomething($(this)) );
```

Comment: what you are trying to do `this` on `doSomething` and in which context its not working.

Comment: I'm trying to pass a reference to the selected radio button to the function I created

Comment: Check these links -  [call a function on click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function)                                     [call a function on change event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897368/how-to-use-a-function-that-takes-arguments-with-jquerys-change-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/change/ and all other jquery events
have a variation of the event handler that accepts eventData as the first param.

```
.change( [eventData ], handler(eventObject) )
```

But in this case your handler function would look for eventData in the eventObject

http://api.jquery.com/event.data/

So your function would look something like this to use this variation.

```
var that = this;
$("input[name='bla']").change({otherThis:that}, doSomething);

function doSomething(e) {
   var $this = $(this);
   var otherThis = e.data.otherThis;
}
```

I added

```
var $this = $(this);
```

to show that

```
$this
```

is the

```
$("input[name='bla']")
```

that was changed. 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What about What about

```
$("input[name='bla']").change(doSomething($(this)));
```

I think you can refer objects using $(this) in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery automatically bind the function call with `this`. You don't have to pass $(this) on.
Only if you want to parse the context of its parent to the function.

For example:

```
$('a.link').change(function (a) {
     console.log(a); // is event object
     console.log($(this)); // is the same as one match of $('a.link'). `this` is binded to the element 
});
```

(after comment)
Or else you can try:

```
$('a.link').change(function (e) { doSomething($(this)); } );
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that? Usually there is no need.

Comment: I want to figure out what the format must be in order to call the function with a parameter, without including the function(e) part.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you refer to this using `$(this)` , but pay attention it will be passed as an object !!

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is to use a variable in the closure scope :

```
var that = this;
('a.link').change(function (e) { doSomething($(that)); } );
```