# JQuery pass value in the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript function that requires one of the arguments. Here is example:

```
function getBldg(filterNum){
    var bldg = $('#frm_bldg');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Application.cfc?method=getBuildings',
        data: {'filterNum':filterNum},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(obj){
        var numRecs = obj.RECORDCOUNT;

        if(obj.STATUS == 200){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
    });
};
```

Here is example of how I call this function:

```
$('#frm_block').on('change',getBldg);
```

So my question is how to pass an argument in `getBldg` function?

I know in javascript I could this: `getBldg(this)` if function was defined in the inline element. In my case I call this function based on the element ID. Here is example of my HTML:

```
<select name="frm_block" id=""frm_block">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
</select>
```

If anyone can help please let me know.

Comment: Wrap the call in an anonymous function: `$('#frm_block').on('change', function() { getBldg('foo'); });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a function that takes arguments with jQuery's change() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897368/how-to-use-a-function-that-takes-arguments-with-jquerys-change-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#frm_block').on('change',function(){
  var filternum = $(this).val()
  getBldg(filternum)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Other way using `event.target`

Ref : https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

```js
function getBldg(filterNum) {
   
   // This is nothig but event object
   // uncomment below to see its content
   // console.log(filterNum);
   
   // to access selected value, you have to use 
   // filterNum.target ....
 console.log( $(filterNum.target).val() );  
};


/*
since you are interested in  inline, so I am not using
$('#frm_block').on('change', function(){
      getBldg($(this).val());
});
*/

$('#frm_block').on('change', getBldg);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="frm_block" id="frm_block">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">Choose-1</option>
  <option value="2">Choose-2</option>
</select>
```